# How can I get specific keys from this?

Tags: javascript, object

I've used `hasOwnProperty` and `typeof` in the past but this one is stumping me...
I'm trying to get all the keys that have keys that match so I can pair them with other keys example:

```
{"meals": [{    
  strIngredient1  : lemons
  strIngredient2    :   paprika
  strIngredient3    :   red onions
  strIngredient4    :   chicken thighs
  strIngredient5    :   vegetable oil
  strMeasure1   :   2 Juice
  strMeasure2   :   4 tsp
  strMeasure3   :   2 finely chopped
  strMeasure4   :   16 skinnless
  strMeasure5   :   
}]}
```

It's apparent that `strIngredient1` matches with `strMeasure1` etc...
Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Ignoring that this isn't valid JS, it's a bad way of storing that information. Is this your own design, i.e. can you change it?

Comment: agree to Chris G, rather let ingredient and measure be properties of the same key

Comment: I'm not sure it is apparent that `strIngredient1` matches with `strMeasure1` - do you just mean that all keys are considered "matching" if the names end with the same number?

Comment: You're going to have to parse this as a string.

Comment: `{ "ingredients": [{ "name": "lemons", "measure": "juice", "quantity": 2 }]}` seems way easier to iterate and compare.

Comment: if you cant restructure the data. you could check the overall length of a meal and divide it by two if there´s always a measure for an ingredient and concatinate the key in a loop then ....

Comment: @johnSmith ... except relying on object property ordering is fragile.

Comment: Not my own design..... believe me whoever thought that this was a good idea doesn't understand the concept OR they really didn't want to make it easy  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explained

In this example, you can see that I've provided the solution in two parts, one being a simple way to simply access `'x'` ingredient from the array of meals, then another solution which will iterate over the array of meals, printing out each individual ingredient.

As I've stated within my solution, you can use `forEach` or alternatively, you can also use functions such as `map` or `reduce` if you wish. In the event that you don't know when to use which, the *basic* rule of thumb is that you'd use `map` or `reduce` if you wish to follow functional programming concepts. The `forEach` solution allows for side effects to happen more easily, etc... I mean this is debatable to a certain extent, but that's the basic idea anyways...

### Edit

I've included a simple log function just for this demo, long story short, when you run this code snippet, personally I find it disgusting how little space is provided for the console window, so log one thing at a time after some delay and clear the console too.

```js
let delay = 0;
const DELAY_INC = 1500;

// Just for this demo, have the ability to log something, 
// after a delay and clear the console.
const log = (arg, alrt) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.clear();
    console.log(arg);
    if (alrt != null) {
      alert(alrt);
    }
  }, delay);
  delay += DELAY_INC;
};

// Your data.
var data = {
  "meals": [{
    strIngredient1: 'lemons',
    strIngredient2: 'paprika',
    strIngredient3: 'red onions',
    strIngredient4: 'chicken thighs',
    strIngredient5: 'vegetable oil',
    strMeasure1: '2 Juice',
    strMeasure2: '4 tsp',
    strMeasure3: '2 finely chopped',
    strMeasure4: '16 skinnless',
    strMeasure5: ''
  }]
};

// Just some demo.
var meals = data.meals;
var meal = meals[0];
var ingredient = meal.strIngredient1;

log(data); // Log the raw data.
log(meals); // Log the array of meals.
log(meal); // Log a specific meal.
log(ingredient); // Log a specific ingredient.

// If you wish to iterate, log each ingredient for each meal. 
data.meals.forEach(meal => Object.keys(meal).forEach(key => log(meal[key])));

// Here's a solution.
const newArray = data.meals.reduce((array, meal) => {
  // Rather than iterate over ALL of the keys, just 
  // do this, basically 50% of the keys. 
  const subArray = Object.keys(meal).filter(key => key.indexOf('strIngredient' == -1));

  // Basically add some ojects to the array.
  subArray.forEach(key => {
    const int = key.replace(/\D/g, '');
    const measureKey = `strMeasure${int}`;
    const ingredientKey = `strIngredient${int}`;

    const obj = {
      ingredient: meal[ingredientKey],
      measure: meal[measureKey]
    };

    array.push(obj);
  });

  // Make sure to return the array.
  return array;
}, []);

// Now just print the resuts, and make sure that you know 
// and alert that the app has finished. 
log(newArray, 'FINISHED');
```

Comment: Beautiful job parsing them but I still have to match them up... 1 to 1 sort of thing :)

Comment: Okay, so I have a basic idea here, I'll edit my answer again, if you don't want to or just cannot restructure the data, I have a basic idea that could allow you to get the result you desire.

Comment: That would be really awesome of you, Thank you!  I've been fighting with this for 2 days..  Trust me if it were my data I would have never structured it like that!

Comment: @John I've updated the answer, I think you'll find that my solution solves your problem? :)

Comment: HUGE thumbs up!! That does indeed answer the question and help greatly, I Thank you so much!!!  Great job!  Happy New Year......Thanks for taking some terrible data and making it usable!!  I can quit pulling my hair out now LOL

Comment: @John haha, it's quite alright, I'm glad you like the solution that I've provided! Happy new year to you too! :)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested or if it helps anyone here is the final product!  All neat and tidy in one array, easy to use! :)   Thank you again JO3-W3B-D3V!

```
getRecipe: function(url) {
    request({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET'
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
            var result = JSON.parse(body);  
            //console.log(result);

             // Just some TESTING.
      var meals = result.meals;  //returns array
      var meal = meals[0]; // returns object
       //console.log(meal);
      // Start here to rename keys and match them to the ingredients.
      const newArray = meals.reduce((array, meal) => {
          // Rather than iterate over ALL of the keys, just 
          // do this, basically 50% of the keys. 
          const subArray = Object.keys(meal).filter(key => key.indexOf('strIngredient' == -1));
         // console.log(subArray);
          // Basically add some ojects to the array.
          subArray.forEach(key => {
              const int = key.replace(/\D/g, '');
              const measureKey = `strMeasure${int}`;
              const ingredientKey = `strIngredient${int}`;

              const obj = {
                  measure: meal[measureKey],
                  ingredient: meal[ingredientKey] 
              };
            //  console.log(obj);  //Testing data before
          if (obj.measure && obj.ingredient != 'undefined' || undefined || "" || null){
              array.push(obj);
            //  console.log(array);  //Testing data after
          }
          });

          const recipeName =  meal.strMeal;
          const instruction = meal.strInstructions;
          const video = meal.strYoutube;
          const thumb = meal.strMealThumb;
          const nation = meal.strArea;
          const category = meal.strCategory;

          const recipe = {recipeName, instruction, video, thumb, nation, category};
          array.push(recipe);
          //console.log(recipe);  Testing full array

          // Make sure to return the array.
          return array;

      }, []);

      // Now just print the resuts, and make sure that you know 
      // and alert that the app has finished.


      console.log(newArray, "FINISHED");
```